# How to get the name of type parameter?

Tags: generics, dart

Dart code:

```dart
main() {
    var x = new X();
    x.go();
}

class M<T> {
    go() {
        print(T);   // !!!! can't be compiled
    }
}

class X extends M<X> {
}
```

You can see in the method `go`, I want to print the information of type parameter `T`, but it can't be compiled.

How to get the name of the type parameter `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this at `compile time` because generic type parameter `T` declared in terms of `to-be-specified-later`.

It may be possible only through `reflection` but that is an expensive operation.

**One small but significant clarification.**

This possibility is planned but not implemented in the current version of the `"mirrors"` library that provides basic reflection support for Dart (SDK version 0.6.3.3_r24898).

Comment: How to get it through `reflection`? I don't know what is the `reflection` you mean.